# Does #pragma once add inclusion guards?

Tags: c++, c

`#pragma once` is not standard, but is supported by compilers like gcc and VC++. It helps to avoid inclusion guards.

But, internally, does the compiler add inclusion guards for `#pragma once`? If not, how does the compiler ensure that such a header is included only once?

Comment: I imagine the compiler simply keeps track of which header files have been included, and where.

Comment: Probably something similar to detecting a cycle in a directed graph

Comment: @OliCharlesworth Possibility cannot be avoided, but in large project, can there not be thousands of header files? So will it be efficient way?

Comment: @Drew: No need for graphs. You just need a list of files for which you've already resolved `#include`s, and simply don't do it twice for those files. It's trivial.

Comment: @ppk: It can be efficient with millions of header files. See "hash table".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm sure it works just like `include_once` in PHP - there is a table of "files that has been included". The compiler, in this case, looks in the list for the file it is about to include and if a file has already been included, don't include it again. If the compiler, while processign the file, sees a `#pragma once`, then add this file to "files that have already been included".

So it's not the same as inclusion guards on a detail level, but it has the same effect as inclusion guards. It also makes the code less portable, since there are plenty of compilers that doesn't support this.

Comment: Actually all the primary compilers support it nowadays.

Comment: "all primary" probably doesn't cover most of the embedded market... And if I can be pointed out that "this won't work if the code is compiled in an embedded compiler", I'm sure I'll use it back on others when their argument fails on that point... ;)

Comment: I've enjoyed writing applications for many embedded solutions using `#pragma once` in GCC since 4.4.0. It's fun to make arguments based on the assumption that someone has never heard of or seen an embedded development environment, but usually prudent to check the facts, first. ;)

Comment: Yes, of course, if you use `gcc` as an embedded compiler, then fine. And I just checked ARM's version, which also support it. But there are people out there using less common compilers, such as IAC (google couldn't even figure out a decent hit for "#pragme once IAC", so I guess it's not that many...) and "vendor specific" compilers... And of course, compilers not produced this decade does sometimes turn up in embedded scenarios...

Comment: Yep, we use the CodeSourcery GCC for ARM.

Answer (score 0):

No, the compiler will not add include guards, but that should not matter, as it won't include the same file again, so it would never get a change to evaluate those guards in the first place.

Comment: That is my question actually, how it know not to include same file.

Comment: @ppk: It can keep track of which filenames it's already `#include`d using computer memory. This is a non-question. How do you know not to post the same question on SO twice?

Comment: One notable exception:  If the same file is `#include`d via two different file-names (eg. symlinks or hard-links on a *nix system), then `#pragma once` will fail to protect, as it is based on the filename. While typical `#ifndef / #define` guards will still work.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Looking at list on right hand side. But that is just predictable duplicate question. But compiler has no chance to predict. It has to be sure (I think)

Comment: @ppk: No. How do you know not to post the same exact question twice? Not a similar question as someone else. But the exact same question as you yourself already posted.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley It's in my memory.

Comment: @ppk: As it is in the compiler's memory. How do you think it tracks its internal state as it performs tasks?

Answer (score -3):

When adding "#pragma once" to file "file.h",the compiler help us ensure the "file.h" will only be opened noce.

But if I have a duplication of "file.h" named "file_copy.h",if it is included, it will be opened.

Comment: That's _what_ it does, not _how_.

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that.